# ie8 + CSS: using -ms-filter in inline style

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, inline-styles

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

I would like to use the above code as an inline style, something like:

```
<div style='-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";'>
```

But I think something is going wacky with the quotation marks all over the place. Can this be done? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd encourage you to just use an external stylesheet.  This would entirely avoid the "quote within a quote" dilemma you're encountering trying to do it with inline styles.

But ...

I believe you *could* simply use either `&quot;` and/or `\"` as needed.

Please try it - and post back what you find :)

Comment: The point of using it as an inline style is that the URL needs to be updated via PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but the solution is to exclude the quotes inside the parentheses. The following syntax can survive IE's belligerence:

```
<div style="-ms-filter:'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=myBackground.jpg, sizingMethod=scale)';">
```

Files should probably be named using web-safe conventions.